# How to force one column layout on custom post type edit page?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, metabox, customization

I've created a plugin using custom post types and I need to force the default two column post page to a single column. At the same time, the **Publish** metabox must move to the bottom. I need to do this via the functions some how.

I have some solutions from WPSE, but the only solution I've found actually hides the "Publish" metabox. I can't seem to figure out why.

Any ideas of how to do this?

Answer (score 8):

There is a filter called `get_user_option_meta-box-order_{$page}` where `$page` is the name of the post type. Just make sure that `submitdiv` is the last value in the array:

```
add_filter( 'get_user_option_meta-box-order_post', 'wpse25793_one_column_for_all' );
function wpse25793_one_column_for_all( $order )
{
    return array(
        'normal'   => join( ",", array(
            'postexcerpt',
            'formatdiv',
            'trackbacksdiv',
            'tagsdiv-post_tag',
            'categorydiv',
            'postimagediv',
            'postcustom',
            'commentstatusdiv',
            'slugdiv',
            'authordiv',
            'submitdiv',
        ) ),
        'side'     => '',
        'advanced' => '',
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried your code. But its not working. My post metabox order looks like this as of now. Title,submit,content,custom metaboxes added by plugins,tags

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to *remove* the original metabox, and then to *re-add* that metabox, with updated parameters. For example, this will move the "Featured Image" meta box from the side column to the main column, for a custom post type with a slug `cpt-slug`:

#### Edit

The parameter for the Publish meta box is `submitdiv`, and the correct callback is `post_submit_meta_box()`; I've updated the code below to reflect these correct parameters. I've also changed the `add_meta_box()` `$context` parameter from `'high'` to `'low'`, so that the Publish meta box will be added at the bottom:

```
<?php
function wpse25793_move_post_metaboxes( $post ) {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;

    remove_meta_box( 'submitdiv', 'cpt-slug', 'side' );
    add_meta_box( 'submitdiv', __( 'Publish' ), 'post_submit_meta_box', 'cpt-slug', 'normal', 'low' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_cpt-slug', 'wpse25793_move_post_metaboxes' );
?>
```

The approach should be the same for the "Publish" meta box. You just need to remove/add the publish meta box instead of the featured image meta box.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the second part of the question  - `How to force one column`, you can do it with `get_user_option_screen_layout_{Post_type}` filter. Let's say for `product` post-type:

```
$func = function( $result, $option, $user ){
    return '1';
};
add_filter( "get_user_option_screen_layout_product", $func, 10, 3 );
```