# How to Remove All Widgets from Dashboard?

Tags: widgets, wp-admin, dashboard

I'm looking for a complete blank Dashboard. No widgets at all and preferably one column.

There are snippets to remove the default WordPress widgets but haven't found anything about the ones added by plugins. Searched all over and seems that this hasn't been asked.

[image: Not blank WordPress Dashboard]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [this Q&A](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/56104/12615), I've learned about the global variable **`$wp_meta_boxes`**. And over there is also the code to *remove the default meta boxes*.

After examining the variable, this is the code I wrote to remove all Dashboard Widgets, **including the ones added by plugins**:

```
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'wpse_73561_remove_all_dashboard_meta_boxes', 9999 );

function wpse_73561_remove_all_dashboard_meta_boxes()
{
    global $wp_meta_boxes;
    $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core'] = array();
    $wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core'] = array();
}
```

---

The answer to **force one column** as a screen option is [from here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/4552/12615):

```
add_filter( 'get_user_option_screen_layout_dashboard', 'wpse_4552_one_column_layout' );

function wpse_4552_one_column_layout( $cols ) {
    if( current_user_can( 'basic_contributor' ) )
        return 1;
    return $cols;
}
```

---

[This one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/25034/12615) provided the code to hide the *Screen Options* and the *Help* tabs:

```
add_filter( 'contextual_help', 'wpse_25034_remove_dashboard_help_tab', 999, 3 );
add_filter( 'screen_options_show_screen', 'wpse_25034_remove_help_tab' );

function wpse_25034_remove_dashboard_help_tab( $old_help, $screen_id, $screen )
{
    if( 'dashboard' != $screen->base )
        return $old_help;

    $screen->remove_help_tabs();
    return $old_help;
}

function wpse_25034_remove_help_tab( $visible )
{
    global $current_screen;
    if( 'dashboard' == $current_screen->base )
        return false;
    return $visible;
}
```

---

Ok, now there's almost nothing in the Dashboard, *what's next?*

A bit of CSS to **hide** the `icon-index` and `H2 title`, and some jQuery to **fill the void**:

```
add_action( 'admin_head-index.php', 'wpse_73561_dashboard_scripts' );

function wpse_73561_dashboard_scripts() {
    ?>
        <style>#icon-index, .wrap h2 {display:none}</style>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                fillTheVoid(); // soon in StackOverflow 
            });
        </script>   
    <?php
}
```

*<sub>[ update ]</sub>*

The filled void can be found in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13505156/1287812).
**Use that** `wpse_73561_dashboard_scripts` function instead of this one.

Comment: Why not just `$wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core'] = array()`?

Comment: @toscho : I knew there was something weird about those lines... Danke schön :)

Answer (score 3):

This will work fine

```
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_dashboard_widgets' );
function remove_dashboard_widgets() {

    global $wp_meta_boxes;
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Remove Default WP metabox in dashboard:

@source https://github.com/vincentorback/clean-wordpress-admin/blob/master/dashboard.php

```
/**
 * Removing dashboard widgets.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_meta_box/
 */
add_action(
    'wp_dashboard_setup',
    function () {
        // Remove the 'Welcome' panel
        remove_action( 'welcome_panel', 'wp_welcome_panel' );

        // Remove 'Site health' metabox
        remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_site_health', 'dashboard', 'normal' );

        // Remove the 'At a Glance' metabox
        remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_right_now', 'dashboard', 'normal' );

        // Remove the 'Activity' metabox
        remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_activity', 'dashboard', 'normal' );

        // Remove the 'WordPress News' metabox
        remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_primary', 'dashboard', 'side' );

        // Remove the 'Quick Draft' metabox
        remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_quick_press', 'dashboard', 'side' );
    }
);
```

#### Remove All WP metabox in dashboard ( for all Plugins ):

@source: unknown

```
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'kdev_remove_dw', 999 );
function kdev_remove_dw() {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;
    $wp_meta_boxes = array();
}
```