# How do I customize the dashboard?

Tags: users, dashboard, permissions

I've been using Drupal for almost two years now so I know nothing about Wordpress.

I have configured everything on my website to work how it should and I love it. I created a new user using the sign-up link and logged in and that user that I just created (Permissions is: Subscriber) can see a lot of information that only an admin can on their Dashboard. Is this normal?? If yes, how do I change it??

They can see the website statistics and plugin information.

The screenshot:

https://image.ibb.co/g0nqUn/Dashboard.jpg

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribers will see the WP Events and News widget, but they shouldn't be seeing the other stuff. Somewhere the theme and/or plugins are adding widgets in a way that's allowing all user levels to see them. You can either hit up the support teams for the themes and plugins that are adding them, or you can create your own plugin with code that removes these metaboxes. You'll need to look up the name for each meta box; here's one example that removes the "Right Now" box:

```
<?php
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'wpse_298944_clear_dash_widgets');
function wpse_298944_clear_dash_widgets() {
     if(!current_user_can(publish_posts)) {
          remove_meta_box('dashboard_right_now', 'dashboard', 'normal');
     }
}
?>
```

Another option is to call the global variable `$wp_meta_boxes` and unset them one by one. See [How to Remove ALL Widgets from Dashboard?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73561/how-to-remove-all-widgets-from-dashboard)