# removing the standard dashboard widgets in WP so I Can replace with custom

Tags: php, functions

The following code has removed some but not all of the widgets from the WP dashboard. I am adding it to my functions file inside my theme. My question is two fold:

1.) What about this is throwing the Use of "undefined constant" errors for remove_dashboard_meta, admin_init and manage_options.

```
function remove_dashboard_meta() {

remove_meta_box( ‘dashboard_incoming_links’, ‘dashboard’, ‘normal’ );
remove_meta_box( ‘dashboard_plugins’, ‘dashboard’, ‘normal’ );
remove_meta_box( ‘dashboard_primary’, ‘dashboard’, ‘side’ );
remove_meta_box( ‘dashboard_secondary’, ‘dashboard’, ‘normal’ );
remove_meta_box( ‘dashboard_quick_press’, ‘dashboard’, ‘side’ );
remove_meta_box( ‘dashboard_recent_drafts’, ‘dashboard’, ‘side’ );
remove_meta_box( ‘dashboard_recent_comments’, ‘dashboard’, ‘normal’ );
remove_meta_box( ‘dashboard_right_now’, ‘dashboard’, ‘normal’ );
remove_meta_box( ‘dashboard_activity’, ‘dashboard’, ‘normal’);//since 3.8
}
add_action( ‘admin_init’, ‘remove_dashboard_meta’ );
```

The second question is that the Elementor overview and WPdeveloper feed are still there. What code is going to remove those? This is WP 5.5

Comment: To remove all widgets from dashboard look at this answer::
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/73562/141970

Comment: Thanks. Is there an option that doesnt prevent any others from being added? Thats what I thought I had above but I am getting those errors and the two residual.

Answer (score 0):

the above example has the wrong comma type probably from copy and pasting. Here is the right type

```
//Disable Default Dashboard Widgets
function remove_dashboard_meta() {
    remove_meta_box('dashboard_incoming_links', 'dashboard', 'normal');
    remove_meta_box('dashboard_plugins', 'dashboard', 'normal');
    remove_meta_box('dashboard_primary', 'dashboard', 'normal');
    remove_meta_box('dashboard_secondary', 'dashboard', 'normal'); 
    remove_meta_box('dashboard_quick_press', 'dashboard', 'side');
    remove_meta_box('dashboard_recent_drafts', 'dashboard', 'side');
    remove_meta_box('dashboard_recent_comments', 'dashboard', 'normal');
    remove_meta_box('dashboard_right_now', 'dashboard', 'normal');
    remove_meta_box('dashboard_activity', 'dashboard', 'normal');
    remove_meta_box('rg_forms_dashboard', 'dashboard', 'normal');
    remove_action('admin_notices', 'update_nag');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'remove_dashboard_meta');
```

The second answer is that to remove Elementor and its overview you use the following code:

```
remove_meta_box('e-dashboard-overview', 'dashboard', 'normal');
```

The Wordpress developers feed widget can be removed with:

```
remove_meta_box('wpdev_feed_widget', 'dashboard', 'normal');
```